# How to increment a list variable based on item index?

Tags: flutter

im getting an error: type `int` is not a subtype of type `List<dynamic>` of function result on pressing add

```
final itemcount = [];

Widget buildItem(BuildContext context, DocumentSnapshot document, int index) {
  return Container(
    child: Flatbutton(
      child:Text("add"),
      onpressed:(){
        itemcount[index]=itemcount[index]+1,
      }
    )
  );
}




             StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                stream: Firestore.instance
                    .collection('products')
                    .where('category', isEqualTo: 'ourstore')
                    .snapshots(),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                    return Center(
                      child: Icon(Icons.photo_library),
                    );
                  } else {
                    return snapshot.data.documents.isEmpty
                        ? Center(child: null)
                        : GridView.builder(
                            itemBuilder: (context, index) => buildItem(
                                context,
                                snapshot.data.documents[index],
                                index),
                            itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                            physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                            gridDelegate:
                                SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                                    // childAspectRatio: 3/4,
                                    crossAxisSpacing: 10,
                                    mainAxisSpacing: 5,
                                    crossAxisCount: 2),
                            shrinkWrap: true,
                            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                          );
                  }
                },
              ),
```

Comment: Add code where you use buildItem function

Comment: I quite don't understand what you are trying to achieve by ```itemcount[index]=itemcount[index]+1,```. Is it adding a +1 to your current value, or is it adding a new member to your list?

Comment: it obviously add 1 to current value. check in your code, you are doing something like following. itemcount = 1. where in place of 1 you are assign any int variable.

Comment: @CarlosSR im trying to increment itemcount[index] by 1 ,that is if   the index is 0 im trying to add 1 to current value of  itemcount[0]

Comment: @tino error you are mentioning is not in this part of code, so add more code where could be error possible.

Comment: @VirenVVarasadiya edited code above

Comment: @tino.. Your code doesn't make sense. Your `itemcount` is empty so it should give you an error `rage is empty` What is the purpose of `itemcount` ? What exactly you want to achieve with this code? Reason you have different error means you have to initialise `itemcount` with some values which I can not see in your code. add it there

Comment: @LonelyWolf thanks initialised itemcount with zero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed the error

had to set the value to zero for every item in the list

code below:

```
 List<int> itemcount = List<int>();

Widget buildItem(
      BuildContext context, DocumentSnapshot document, int index) {


    itemcount.add(0);

return Container(
    child: Flatbutton(
      child:Text("add"),
      onpressed:(){

       setState(() {
       itemcount[index]++;

       });
      }
    )
  );

}
```